# Nifi - SplitJson retaining all other info

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jsonpath

Working in Nifi, I have the following json structure in the content of a flow file:

```
{
    "firstname": "fred",
    "lastname": "jackson",
    "dob": "19550607",
    "children": [{
            "firstname": "janet",
            "lastname": "jackson",
            "dob": "20020607"
        },
        {
            "firstname": "michael",
            "lastname": "jackson",
            "dob": "20010201"
        },
        {
            "firstname": "tito",
            "lastname": "jackson",
            "dob": "20030707"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to split this such that I would have three (3) flowfiles, each containing the top level info, but with just one child.  For example one of them would look like this:

```
{
    "firstname": "fred",
    "lastname": "jackson",
    "dob": "19550607",
    "children": {
        "firstname": "janet",
        "lastname": "jackson",
        "dob": "20020607"
    }
}
```

Again, I would have three different flow files, one for each child.  The output does not have to look exactly like this.  The important thing is that I am able to split the struture, yet maintain the common data in each of the result flow files.

I tried using SplitJson with a JSONExpression of "$.children", which does give me the three flow files, but I loose the parent info.  I could save the key/values for the common elements in attributes, split, and then add them, but the parent information can be more complex than my example (dynamic fields, etc), so I am unsure how I would do this.

Appreciate any ideas or thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [ForkRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ForkRecord/index.html) with a JSON Reader/Writer.

Set `Include Parent Fields` to `true` to retain the parent fields.

However, this may flatten the JSON in a way that you don't want - give it a try.

Alternatively, look at [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/) which gives a lot more flexibility, but is quite complex to work out the appropriate spec. You can use https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception to test your JOLT Specs.

Comment: Sort of as I expected.  Hopefully for something easier, but what are you gonna do. Time to dive into JOLT.  Thanks for the input.